Confusion: Indentation for some lines, but none for other for Corollary
Here's the image:

I'm not sure why there is an indentation before some lines, but none for other. I didn't use \corollary but rather used textbf{Corollary...}.
Here's the whole code if it's helpful.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Libraries.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]

% Math shortcuts.
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\textit{#1}}


% Property settings.
\pagestyle{headings}

% Attr.
\title{STA347 \\ Lecture Review}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
 
\section{Sample Space, Event, Structured Randomness}
    \definition{Sample space $\&$ Event}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Sample Space: The collection of all possible outcomes, denoted $\Omega$
        \subitem Example: For a coin toss, $\Omega=\{1,-1\}$, whereby 1 represents Head, -1 represents Tail;
        \item Event: A well-defined subset of $\Omega$.
    \end{itemize}
    \definition[Structured Randomness] 
    Denote the outcomes of an experiment as $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$. Repeating the experiment infinitely close time will make the average to converge, and we denote this convergence as expectation:
    $$\mb{E}(X)=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n},$$
    where X is a random variable.
    
\section{Expectations}
    \textcolor{blue}{"Expectation only applies to random variables; Probability only applies to events."}
    \begin{definition}[Random Variable]
        $X$ is called a random variable it it's a function from $\Omega$ to $\mb{R}$. Equivalently, $X(\omega)\in \mb{R}$ whereby $\omega \in \Omega$
    \end{definition}
    \definition[Indicator Functions]Let $A\in \Omega$ be an event. $I_A$ is the indicator function of $A$ if $$I_A(\omega)=1 \begin{cases}1&\text{if } \omega \in A \\0&\text{if } \omega \not \in A\end{cases}$$
    Intuitively, the function determines whether a random variable belongs to an event.\\ 
    * Note that (1) $I_A$ is a random variable (2) $I_A$ must be defined over all elements in $\Omega$.
    
    \subsection{Intuitive Definition of Probability}
    \definition[Probability]
        $$\mb{P}(A)=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{I_A(X_1)+...+I_A(X_n)}{n}=\mb{E}(I_A),$$
        where  $I_A(\omega)=1 \begin{cases}1&\text{if event A occurs in experiment $i$-th} \\0&\text{else } \end{cases}$\\ \\
    \subsection{Axioms and Corollaries}
    \axiom{Axioms of Expectations}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Axiom 1: $\mb{E}(X) \geq 0$ if $X \geq 0$;
        \item Axiom 2: If $c$ is a constant, then $\mb{E}(cX)=c\mb{E}(X)$;
        \item Axiom 3: $\mb{E}(X_1+X_2)=\mb{E}(X_1)+E(X_2)$;
        \item Axiom 4: $\mb{E}(1)=1$;
        \item Axiom 5: If a sequence of non-negative random variables $X_n(w)$ increases monotonically to $X(w)$, then $\mb{E}(X)=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(X_n)$.
    \end{itemize}

    \theorem[Consequence of Axiom 5]
    If $A_1, A_2$ are disjoint events , then $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 = P(A_1)+P(A_2) \iff \mb{E}(I_{A_1}+I_{A_2})=\mb{E}(I_{A_1})+\mb{E}(I_{A_2})$$
    
    \proposition
    If there are $A_1,A_2,...$ countably many disjoint events, then 
    $$\mb{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}A_i)=\Sigma^\infty_{i=1}\mb{P}(A_i)$$

    \corollary {Corollaries}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Corollary 1: For $n \geq 2, \mb{E}[c_1X_1+...+c_nX_n]=c_1\mb{E}(X_1)+...+c_n\mb{E}(X_n)$
        \item Corollary 2: If $X\leq Y,$ then $\mb{E}(X) \leq \mb{E}(Y)$
        \item Corollary 3: $|\mb{E}(X)| \leq \mb{E}(|X|)$
        \item Corollary 4 (Fatou's Lemma): $\forall i \geq 1,$ if $X_i$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables $\wedge X_i \rightarrow X$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$, then $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \text{inf}_{k\geq n} \mb{E}(X_k) \geq \mb{E}(X)$\\
        \textcolor{blue}{*Corollary 4 is a more generalized version of Axiom 5, with the monotonicity assumption dropped.}

    \end{itemize}

    \subsection{Proofs of Corollaries}

    
    \textbf{Corollary 1}: For $n \geq 2, \mb{E}[c_1X_1+...+c_nX_n]=c_1\mb{E}(X_1)+...+c_n\mb{E}(X_n)$\\
    
    
    \textbf{Corollary 2}: If $X\leq Y,$ then $\mb{E}(X) \leq \mb{E}(Y)$
    \proof Let $Z = Y - X$. Assume $X \leq Y \implies Z \geq 0$ \\
    By A1, $$\mb{E}(Z) \geq 0$$
    By A2 and A3, $$\mb{E}(Z)=\mb{E}(Y-X)=\mb{E}(Y)-\mb{E}(X) $$
    Thus, 
    $$\mb{E}(Y)-\mb{E}(X) \geq 0$$
    $$\mb{E}(Y) \geq \mb{E}(X)$$
    \qed

    \textbf{Corollary 3}:$|\mb{E}(X)| \leq \mb{E}(|X|)$\\

    \textbf{Fatou's Lemma}:$\forall i \geq 1,$ if $X_i$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables $\wedge X_i \rightarrow X$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$, then $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \text{inf}_{k\geq n} \mb{E}(X_k) \geq \mb{E}(X)$



    
\end{document}


Welcome! Just out of curiosity, how are you compiling your file? If you had given a complete example that one can compile I would not need to ask.

The whole code would include what you used to produce "2.3 Proofs of Corollaries".  And since I'm guessing that's \section, the whole code would also include everything from \documentclass through \end{document}.  And since that would make it LaTeX, see Why is [ ... ] preferable to $$ ... $$?.

Why are you manually doing this when newtheorem exists? And don't use proof like that. Use it as the env it 7s and it will place the qed for you.

Hi @mickep, I've included the whole code. Hope it works!

Hey @daleif, I opted for this instead because I created a newcommand whereby \corollary would automatically be numbered by the section. However, in this section, I don't want my corollary to be numbered by section, but rather just 1,2,3,4.
I'd appreciate any advice on how to improve upon this!

It is still a huge waste of time and effort. Much easier to just mess with the numbering.

By default after a section there is not indentation of normal paragraphs, and what you have is not  a "Corollary" environment, but just a normal paragraph starting with that word in bold, so the second paragraph is indented as any normal plain text.
By default, the theorem environment avoid this, and moreover will be not be numbered by section in an article document. So, simply do not force the \newtheorem to do that if you want a simple counter.
Example:

\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\textbf{Corollary 1. } foo \par
\textbf{Corollary 2. } bar \par
\textbf{Corollary 3. } baz \par
\section{foo}
\begin{cor}  foo  \end{cor} 
\begin{cor}  bar  \end{cor}
\begin{cor}  baz  \end{cor}
\end{document}

Note that no only the indentation, but also the vertical spaces and the font are  wrong (=normal paragraphs) in the first section of the example.
